# Git rebase, fix conflicts, then push is rejected

Tags: git, rebase, git-merge-conflict

When I **rebase**, and there are **conflicts which I then resolve**, I get the following message:

> hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind

---

We have 2 branches:

- `master` is our base
- `feature/fix-input-height` (new feature to merge into master)

I am preparing `feature/fix-input-height` by rebasing master to locally resolve conflicts

```
git checkout master
git pull origin master

git checkout feature/fix-input-height
git pull origin feature/fix-input-height

git rebase master
```

---

- Conflicts arise
- I resolve them
- Then attempt to push the new feature branch

```
git push origin feature/fix-input-height
```

And end up with that **rejected error message** again:

> hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind

---

Everyone on stackoverflow suggests:

```
git push origin -f feature/fix-input-height
```

**But forcing the push just feels wrong**

Comment: only force will help you

Comment: you must use force if your tip is behind. You can not use force only by creating a new branch and forget the old one.

Answer (score 20):

Rebase works by *copying* commits.  You start with, e.g.:

```
...--o--o--o   <-- master
      \
       A--B--C   <-- feature/fix-input-height (HEAD)
```

and end up with:

```
             A'-B'-C'  <-- feature/fix-input-height
            /
...--o--o--o   <-- master
      \
       A--B--C   [previous feature/fix-input-height, now abandoned]
```

But the *other* repository—the one that's not yours, that you ask your Git to `git push` to—still has the original commits.  You don't have those commits any more.  You have new and improved ones instead, but *they don't know that.*  All they know is that you're asking them to *throw away* three perfectly good commits.

So they say *No, I won't throw those away.  Not unless you use a forceful command, rather than a polite request, at least.*

That's why you need `--force`, or—better, though people don't use it a lot—`--force-with-lease`.  Either way you tell them: *Yes, I mean that you should throw out your commits.*  The difference between these two is that `--force` just says: *Throw out your commits!  Use this instead!*  Using `--force-with-lease` says: *I think your `feature/fix-input-height` names commit `C`.  If so: Throw out those commits!  Use this instead!*  It will fail if someone has added commit `D`, that you don't have and therefore did not include in your rebase.

Comment: excellent write up, I have a better understanding of rebasing now. thanks!

Answer (score 3):

[Torek's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56013029/7426932) is undoubtfully the most insightful answer here but considering your concerns and the comments you added since then, your problem is more political than technical and you're right to worry about it.

The main concern here should be « Is anybody else working on *feature/fix-input-height* or is it a private branch ? »

If this "feature" branch is shared, then you shouldn't rebase since somebody else would still trying to applying changes to the previous reference. If it's fully private (that's one of the purposes the branches are for), then you may move it freely.

However, to make Git happy and to avoid your co-worker to manually reset their own local copy of your branch, what I would probably do is to preserve the transitive path from the old version to the new one. That is :

- Merge your branch on top of *master*, but choosing only the left side modifications when resolving a conflict, which would actually discard everything from your feature branch and leave *master* unchanged. But this  still would introduce a merge point ;
- Replay all commits you actually want to move on top of your new *feature* branch.

Answer (score 2):

## Why not merge ?

If you feel wrong using `--force` so often, maybe you need to switch to a *fast forward workflow* : a workflow where pushed commits don't change, ever.

This workflow requires to never use any history-rewriting command, like `rebase`.

When you want to take master's changes into your branch, just do the following :

```
git checkout master # Go on your local master branch
git pull            # Make sure is up to date
git checkout -      # Go back to the previous branch (you can use git checkout mybranch instead)
git merge master    # Merge master into your branch
git push            # Push the fast-forward changes to the repository
```

This will never trigger a `non-fast-forward` error or require a `--force` flag, because the only thing you do using theses commands is **adding commits** not rewriting them.

---

If you worry that all theses merge will clutter your `git log` output, remember that there is an option `--no-merges` to add them which does a wonderful job for fast-forward workflows.

Answer (score 0):

Here are my thoughts, someone correct me if I am wrong.

If you hate the `--force` so much, I guess you could create additional branch from your feature branch which will serve you only for rebasing and solving conflicts. For example `git checkout -b feature/fix-input-height-rebase`.

Now you can execute `git rebase master`, resolve the conflicts and push: `git push --set-upstream origin feature/fix-input-height-rebase`.

Only problem (or annoyance) that I see with this approach is that you have to abandon the previous pull request and create another one with rebase branch as a source branch and master as a target branch.