# Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind

Tags: git

Two branches

- **main**
- **local_issue_branch**

---

- Time T1 - Did some changes in local_issue and pushed ( git push )
- Time T2 - Some changes were also done in the **main** branch by some
  other fellow.
- Time T3 - Some changes are done in **local_issue_branch**

---

Now I want to push changes into remote T3

- git checkout **main**
- git pull
- git checkout **local_issue_branch**
- git rebase **main**
- git push

I am getting this message

```
To bitbucket.org:xyzabc/itrp.git
 ! [rejected]            bugfix/ITRP_18238-auth_issue -> bugfix/ITRP_18238-auth_issue (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'bitbucket.org:xyzabc/itrp.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

I can push to local_issue_branch only with

```
git push --force
```

Is this the right approach? Why *--force* is required?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56013029/7976758

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Git rebase, fix conflicts, then push is rejected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56012817/git-rebase-fix-conflicts-then-push-is-rejected)

Comment: `--force` isn't *required* because rebasing isn't required in the first place, but it's usually what you want. Or rather, `--force-with-lease` may be what you want as it inserts an extra safety check first. But once you choose to rebase, you must indeed direct the other Git to throw out the replaced commits in favor of the replacements. Mercurial's "evolve" extension was superior in many ways but Git doesn't have it (Mercurial didn't either, as it was an extension).

Comment: The same error message of 'Updates was rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind' also appears if I run these command sequences - (1) git checkout main (2) git pull (3) git checkout local_issue_branch (4) git rebase main (5) git push